# is it impossible aws dynamodb design with low-cost with normal website(bbs, blog, press...)?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

**The thing what i want do**:
I'm thinking about use aws dynamodb as my new web site(press and bbs mixed type) main server.
But I can't design database, because dynamodb maybe cannot satisfy my requirements.
Somebody knows how can i do?

**Foundation**
My boss's plan is spawning many websites and close it several days after if it's traffic is low. (and go on until it success)
He has many domain names (over hundreads) and want make many websites.
And he also wants selling our system for web solution to customers. ( internet newspaper, blogs, magazines, etc... )
It is very large plan, anyway i must design the system.

**Situation**
first, most of website is going trashcan after several days.
so make each websites on on-premise server is not good way because it means too much manual-jobs. (just deploying the site, undeploying the site)
And also on-premised pricing is not good in this case because we can't predict any webserver is closing (because traffic size lower than survive-line), or survive because traffic is grow faster.
i guess 80% of sites are just ghost sites.

second, the amount of **spawining** websites are not measurable. Because my boss always yelled me 'as many as can!'

And I also consider about this project is abandoned by my company after launching some month after. (maybe they want keep-and-not-maintain mode with not consume many price)

Anyway, ths problem is the...
1. can't predict how many sites are alive and gets high traffic.
2. can't predict how many sites are ghosts or few traffics (under 1000users/days).
3. even the project is abandoned, the'll want keep-and-not-maintain-mode (with lowcost as they can)

conslusion is
1. most sites are going to keep-and-not-maintain-mode. it's cost must low
2. some few sites are 'burst' in after times. it must support this situation also.

**So next is my answer:**
**Server** : full faas serverless with stateless server (lambda, cloudrun, function, etc... i think cloudrun is best because development is very it can easy using my own docker)
the reason is...
if this website is 'just keep and not maintain it', we did not pay for it. or very small price.
if the site growing up or traffic is burst, it can support on-live.

**Database** : serverless because it's traffic is not measurable in this stage.
there only two serverless (means needs no pay for provisioned instance). Aurora and Dynamodb.

**Aurora** is my first choice because I always using mysql or mariadb in webservice.
But there is two problem.
Aurora serverless is too sensitive acu scaling. and it never going scale-down until 5 minutes flowed. (and if it scaled up to 4 acu, 5*4=20acu/min. just one connection and query once, but pricing=$0.03)
It is pretty sure if one of these site's traffic is changed from 'nobody use it' to 'a few people comes', Autoscale price is going to very higher. even i set max acu scale limit to 1, there are another problems. (well-known problems). If aurora start from cold, it takes very long time(about 30seconds). And if it is scaling, it also takes some delay.
Anyway, i can't make good pricing design for Aurora.

So I moved on **Dynamodb**.
It has very good pricing rules. In on-demand mode, under $2 per 1,000,000 rcu.
I guess most of site data is stored in S3. So read/write other data is not much than 1kb/4kb, and even i transaction for each unit, under $2 per 500,000rcu.

**Actual Problem**
But it has trap point.
If I do scan, its pricing is going to very higher. because returns a lot of data (until 1mb). I accepted. So I must using query. But query is working same as 'scan in a partition'. And pricing is going to scanned amount of read-write-units(until 1mb). So if I have 100 items in a key and query just one item (total 100 members and just select one of that members), the dynamodb charges 100 times pricing because it scanned 100 items. (assume each item lower than 1kb). I cant believe it. (x100 pricing) so googled it.
I found many people are design dynamodb seperated hash-key. (like 'members-startfrom-a', 'members-startfrom-b', ... )

**Question**
Is it normal?
In this time, I think dynamodb cannot support normal website (bbs or press, or blog). because they are rdb optimized structures. Even paging articles needs full-scan(or partitioned full-scan).  Is it right? or there is a 'migration rules' for rdb user to dynamodb user?
Someone can show me 'case-study'?
Most case people use dynamodb as subdb.

Comment: DynamoDB is capable of supporting any sized site or application. The choice of DB engine is dependent on the use case, access patterns, and is often a trade off between many things like speed/ease of development, ease of querying, developer familiarity, etc. We use DynamoDB as our primary (only) DB for all our applications, but for a blog, or BB type application, I’d probably use a RDB.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB has 2 types of reads: strongly consistent of 4K / item = 1 RCU and 
eventualy consistent of 4k / item = 0.5 RCU. So if your object is less than 4KB and you do a eventually consistent read this will cost only 0.5 RCU.
Then you have

Get , this is bringing one item ,

BatchGetItem , max 100 items ,

Query as you said , partial scan inside one partition

Scan , read the whole table

If you want to show many items , then you need one of the last 3, BatchGetItem , Query or Scan.

Not sure I understand your example, I think you should look on Get and BatchGet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You clarify my problem.
The main question is 'Is there any way about get a item in dynamodb(with condition), without pay for all scanned data?'

Comment: If there is a table with 100 items, each item has 'date'. if rdb case, 'select * from table where date = '2019-12-30 11:30:21' query returns 3 items. Same case on dynamodb, If i scan and filter data, following my understand, dynamodb charges price for 100(whole) data. And following my understand, Query is same way but only search from a paratition. (like aws athena does). In this case, minimum unit is 4kb. So they charges 4kb*100items (=100rcu) charges to me. I confused. Is the only reduce cost is design of very scattered partition?

Comment: if you partition by date then you get only the 3 items. If you scan , yes, then you get the 100 items. If you sue an index then you get what you want only.

Comment: i know your answer. but problem is here : is same charging 'get only 3 items' and 'get 100 items'? because inner work in dynamodb, it charges anyway 100 item compare and charge every item, even i returned only 3 items by condition. if no(only charges returned item 3), my problem is solved. if yes, finding an item from dynamodb is pretty expensive by their design.

Comment: if you use an index it's only 3 , not 100. 100 is if you scan . Hope this helps ! Good luck with your interesting project!

Comment: You mean rcu price charging based only amount of row and size of returned data from built-in aws functions. Thank you. That's exactly I want!